# Designing a CRUD test suite

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm writing a suite of black-box automated tests for our application. I keep bumping into the same design problem, so I was wondering what people here think about it.

Basically, it's a simple CRUD system. For argument's sake, let's see you're testing the screens to create, view, edit and delete user accounts. What I would *like* to do is write one test which tests that user creation works correctly, another test that checks that viewing a user shows you the same data as you originally typed in, another test that checks that editing a user works, and finally a test that deleting a user is OK.

The trouble is, if I do that, then the tests must be run in a certain order, or they won't work. (E.g., you can't delete a user that hasn't been created yet.) Now some say that the test setup should create everything that the test needs, and the teardown should put the system back into a consistent state. But think about it... the Create User test is going to need to delete that user afterwards, and the Delete User test will have to create a user first... so the two tests now have identical code, and the only difference is whether that code is in the setup / body / teardown. That just seems *wrong*.

In short, I seem to be faced with several alternatives, all of which seem broken:

1. Use setup to create users and teardown to delete them. This duplicates all of the Create User and Delete User test code as setup / teardown code.
2. Force the tests to run in a specific order. This violates the principle that tests should work in isolation and be runnable in any order.
3. Write one *giant* test which creates a user, views the user, edits the user, and then deletes the user, all as one huge monolithic block.

Note that creating a user is not a trivial matter; there's quite a lot of steps involved. Similarly, when deleting a user you have to specify what to do with their assigned projects, etc. It's not a trivial operation by any means.

Now, if this were a *white-box* test, I could mock the user account objects, or mock the database that holds them, or even prod the real database on disk. But these are *black box* tests, which test only the external, user-visible interface. (I.e., clicking buttons on a screen.) The idea is to test the whole system from end to end, without modifying it [except through GUI commands, obviously].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the same issue.  We've taken two paths.  In one style of test, we use the setup and teardown as you suggest to create the data (users, tickets, whatever) that the test needs.  In the other style, we use pre-existing test data in the database.  So, for example, if the test is `AdminShouldBeAbleToCreateUser`, we don't do either of those, because that's the test itself.  But if the test is `ExistingUserShouldBeAbleToCreateTicket`, we use a pre-defined user in the test data, and if the test is `UserShouldBeAbleToDeleteOwnTicket`, we use a pre-defined user and create the ticket in the setup.